# Is it safe to access (read-only) R matrices within a Rcpp::List from an openMP parallelized loop using a std::vector<double*>?

Tags: multithreading, memory, openmp, rcpp, rcpparmadillo

I wrote a piece of Rcpp code to speed up some treatment involving a R list of numeric matrices.
As the number of matrix within the R list may reach hundreds of thousands, I started parallelizing this Rcpp code using openMP.

But as explained multiple times in many posts here, Rcpp objects (e.g. `Rcpp::List` and `Rcpp::NumericMatrix`) cannot be safely involved in multi-threaded sections, as they are subject to  R's memory management and its garbage collector.

So I made and tested two versions of the multi-threaded Rcpp function:

i) - One uses a `const arma::field<arma::mat>` as function 1st parameter and using it as is in the parallelized omp section.

```
Rcpp::List myRcppFunction1(const arma::field<arma::mat> & InField,
                           unsigned int threads_nb);
```

However, this implies deep copy of the data when the R-side list is implicitly converted to arma::fieldarma::mat.

ii) - The other uses a Rcpp::List as 1st parameter, and defines
a `std::vector<double*>` whose elements point to the matrix
addresses inside the `Rcpp::List`. Only this std::vector
is involved in the parallelized section, as following:

```
Rcpp::List myRcppFunction2(const Rcpp::List & InList,
                           arma::uword col_nb,
                           arma::uword row_nb,
                           unsigned int threads_nb){
  int n = InList.length();

  // vector storing the memory address of each matrix of InList
  std::vector<double*> InMatPtrVec(n);

  // fill the std::vector
  for(size_t i=0; i<InMatPtrVec.size(); ++i){
    NumericMatrix m = InList[i];
    InMatPtrVec[i] = &(m[0]);
  }
  // an writable arma::field<arma::mat> shared by all threads. 
  arma::field<arma::mat> OutField(n);

  // multi-threaded section
  #pragma omp parallel num_threads(threads_nb)
  {
    #pragma omp for
    for(arma::uword i=0; i < n; ++i){

      // Here arma::mat advanced constructor allows to re-use
      // a R memory block without involving the R object owning
      // this memory in the parallelized section.
      const arma::mat InMat_i(InMatPtrVec[i], col_nb, row_nb, false, true);

      // do something involving InMat_i (read only)
      // ...

      // A reference to OutField[i]
      arma::mat & OutMat_i = OutField[i];
      // do something involving OutMat_i (read/write).
      // ...

    } // end of parallelized for loop

  } // end of multi-threaded section

  // Return outputs as a R list
  return(Rcpp::List::create(OutField, n);
}
```

This 2nd version using pointers and arma::mat advanced constructor avoid a deep copy of the R side list data.

This is how I call these functions in a R session:

```
# This list may contain hundreds of thousands of numeric matrix
inputList = list(...)
outputList1 = myRcppFunction1(inputList, threads_nb=4)
outputList2 = myRcppFunction2(inputList, threads_nb=4)
```

Both versions seem to do the job and gives the same results.
I have repetitively tested it and have never encountered any segfault nor crashes nor stack imbalance warnings yet.

Moreover, I lastly did tests in **gctorture(TRUE)** context and both versions kept working as expected.

Is this a sufficient "proof" that both versions and especially the second one using `std::vector<double*>` are safe?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow, and Rcpp!  Yours is a very long message and I won't have time to diagnose it liene by line -- but it seems you are doing the right thing. One thing to keep in mind is that the _efficient_ RcppArmadillo constructors re-use R memory and _could_ be affected by garbage collection.  Overall, tbe best extended discussion of all these topics is still in the RcppParallel vignette.

Comment: I'm not a R specialist at all, and I'm not sure to fully understand all the implications of the question, but it seems to me that from the moment the objects *could* be affected by the garbage collection, then this code can not be 100% safe.

Comment: You ask _Is this a sufficient "proof"_ and nobody can answer or "prove" this. You did the right thing by also running `gctorture()` and if it all works and your design is sounds ... then you can be reasonably optimistic that you have done this correctly.  But at the end of the day it is a _software project_ and every non-triivial one devils lurking in the details.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt respond and advice @DirkEddelbuettel. I will have a deeper look at the RcppParallel vignette too.